# Backup doubts: how can I use my backup files

Tags: backup, migration

I'm using Deja Dup for backing up my files and I have some doubts.

1) can I restore an old backup on a new computer (so with different drivers, partitions..)? For example migrating from ubuntu x.x to ubuntu x.x but on a new machine.

2) Can I restore a backup on other distros (previous version of Ubuntu but also fedora etc..)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely you can. In addition to other solution, I'll add steps to do that quoted from [DejaDup wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/DejaDup/Help/Restore/Full).

1. Open Déjà Dup. Choose “Applications → Accessories → Déjà Dup Backup
   Tool”.
2. Click on the big “Restore” button.
3. A dialog will appear asking where your backup files are stored (your
   “Backup location”). Choose it from the dropdown or choose “Other…”.
   On this same screen, select whether you encrypted the backup or not.
   Click “Forward”.
4. Choose the date you want to restore from. Usually you can just leave
   this alone, as the default is the most recent backup. Click
   “Forward”.
5. Choose where to restore. Since this is a full system backup, leave
   it as the default (to restore over your current install). Click
   “Forward”.
6. Review your selections and click “Restore”.
7. Wait. Your files won’t appear in your home directory until the
   entire restore is finished.
8. Reinstall any programs that you enjoyed in your previous install.

Comment: Thanks ! I couldn't vote 'cause I haven' the earn 15points yet..

Comment: @fedefedericorico But you can mark as answer if it solves your problem just click the little grey ☑ under the "0" now turning it  into green.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes.

Deja Dup is a file-based backup utility, which is actually a front-end to Duplicity, and can restore those files to any drive or operating system independent of things like filesystem type or partition size.

You can use it to back up only certain folders, or to back up all the files and directories in a filesystem.  What it won't back up is your partition table, filesystem type, boot loaders etc.  This makes it flexible.

Restoring would involve restoring to a folder of your choice.  If you wanted to restore system folders (ie all of `/` including `/bin`, `/lib` and so forth) you could do this, via something like a live CD, if you know how to do the partitioning and install the boot manager later.  But a simpler, typical use case would be, you re-install Ubuntu (or an OS of your choice), then restore your data files and folders you need to a certain directory where you can then access them.  You cannot directly browse the files that are backed up, you need to restore them to somewhere first then browse them from there.

If you back up from a Linux based system and restore to a Linux based system it should preserve file permissions.

You can even restore the backed up files from within Windows, though the process is somewhat involved and not for the faint-hearted.  But the ability to restore from a Live CD would mean you can restore to just about file system anywhere.

Comment: Thank  you for the very precise answer!  Unluckily I can't vote the answer but I appreciate your suggestion